# How do I change the desktop wallpaper to a dual screen image

Tags: desktop-background

I found many articles that were similar to mine, but none with my specific problem.

I have a dual screen setup and I am using Ubuntu 11.10- I changed my wallpaper from one dual screen image (1600X600) to another (2560X1024) using the System Settings > Appearance > Wallpapers menu.

It worked fine. Then (being an idiot) I decided I wanted to try some different ones that Ubuntu provided.

I chose one that came packaged (*The Grass Ain't Greener 2000X1250*) then I decided to go back to the original. This is where the problem started. Using the Wallpaper menu, I could no longer select any images that have previously been used as wallpapers. What Gives?

Answer (score 1):

It's looking only in specific locations for the wallpapers.  In order to use your own, you will need to either locate the pictures you used, by pressing the "+" button below the thumbnails, and browsing for the picture.  I believe it defaults to looking in the "Pictures" folder in your home directory, but you can browse any folder.

Don't forget to set the option above the theme name to "Span" if you want it to span both monitors instead of repeating.